# orientationchange event is not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, orientation, screen-orientation

I am trying to detect the orientation change in the mobile devices,iphone and ipads.

I am using the below code:

```
 $(window).bind("orientationchange", function (event) {
    alert(event.orientation);

    position = $.event.special.orientationchange.orientation();

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here the value of alert i.e. event.orientation is displaying as "Undefined", where as i have read in some post that it does support for detecting the orientation.
Also in the jquery documentation it is written to better use "event.orientation" instead of "window.orientation" but none of these are returning the required result both are returning "undefined".

So i have used "$.event.special.orientationchange.orientation();" to detect the orientation.

But i want to use the functionality defined in the documentation of jquery as event.orientation. as in [link](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

Also in my code "$.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled" is set to true, as given in the above link.

Please suggest me any possible solution for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but just in case anyone else comes across it, you have to use window.orientation, and that is expressed in degrees:

```
portrait: 0
portrait (upside down): 180 
landscape: (counterclockwise): 90
landscape: (clockwise): -90
```

Answer (score 1):

event.orientation isn't always set. I had this "undefined" problem in IOS safari. Instead, try using window.orientation:

```
//trigger a button click when orientation is changed to landscape mode
$(window).on('orientationchange', function(event) {
    if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
        $('.close-button').click();
    }
});
```

window.orientation can be 0 or 180 (portrait mode), or 90 or -90 (landscape mode)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Just in case some one come across this question. 
Try window.screen.orientation.type

```
jQuery( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
    if(window.screen.orientation.type == 'landscape-primary')
    {

    }
    if(window.screen.orientation.type == 'portrait-primary')
    {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange',function(){
    if(event.orientation == 'portrait'){
        alert('portrait');
    }
    else if(event.orientation == 'landscape') {
        alert('landscape');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on("orientationchange", function (event) {
```